# How to uninstall manually openerp module

Tags: python, odoo

I have installed a module on openerp v7 that I would like to uninstall.

Using the interface fails, i get an error during the uninstall process.

Is there a 'manual' way to uninstall a module ?  Is it sufficient to remove the module folder under `addons/` or is there any other things to do, to make it in the cleanest way ?

Here is the error I get when i try to uninstall a module through the interface:

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1132, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid,     self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 197, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 495, in button_immediate_uninstall
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_uninstall,     context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 475, in _button_immediate_function
    _, pool = pooler.restart_pool(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/pooler.py", line 39, in restart_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.new(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 218, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 354, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 256, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report,     skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 188, in load_module_graph
    load_data(module_name, idref, mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 76, in <lambda>
    load_data = lambda *args: _load_data(cr, *args, kind='data')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-    py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 124, in _load_data
    tools.convert_xml_import(cr, module_name, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20131016_232725-py2.7.egg/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 945, in convert_xml_import
    relaxng.assert_(doc)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3027, in lxml.etree._Validator.assert_     (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:129517)
AssertionError: Did not expect text in element record content, line 33
```

Sorry for this long trace..

At first I suspected one of the xml files to wrong, but as I get the same error when I try to install a module manually, I think something else is going wrong but I can't see what.

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Removing the module's code from `addons/`is not enough - this will break OpenERP.

**Solution 1 - Try to resolve the error you have during normal uninstall**

This method is recommended because OpenERP does the job cleanly. Look at the error you have during uninstallation and try to imagine what could be the problem. Post the error trace here for further help.

**Solution 2 - Manual uninstall**

My procedure is based on OpenERP v6.0 but it should be very similar in OpenERP v7.

1. Backup your database :). Do it. It's very probable that you break something during this procedure.
2. Find what records were created during the installation or the update of the module.

   - Look at `__openerp__.py` to see which XML files are taken into account when installing and updating the module. Alternatively, consider all XML files in the module's directories.
   - Search for records created by this modules during install or update. There should be XML elements like `<record ...model='...'>` inside these files. The `model` attribute tells you in which datatable the record resides. If you are using a Unix-like system, you can try the following command in the module's root directory:

   `grep -r -n -A 5 --include="*.xml" \<record *`
3. Delete these records. You'll use some database interface tool such as `PgAdmin` or `pqsl` and find the records discovered in the previous step.

   For example, the following XML line defines a record in the `ir_cron` datatable:

   `<record model="ir.cron" id="ir_cron_account_fiscalyear_close">`

   Knowing that, you can find the record based on the data defined for this record in the XML file.
4. Find and delete all the menu items defined by the module. As above, search the XML files for `<menuitem ...>` elements. Look for related records in the `ir_ui_menu` datatable.
5. Discover which `models` were defined by the module. Try the following command:

   `grep -r -n -C 5 --include="*.py" "_name = " *`

   Only pay attention to models defined in objects that derive from `osv.osv` (`osv.Model` in OpenERP v7). They define persistent models stored in the database. Objects descendant from `osv.osv_memory` (`osv.TransientModel` in v7) are not stored in the database.

   Be careful and avoid deleting models defined in parent objects. Look at the `_inherit` property of the object to give you an idea about that. In this case, you want to only delete the columns added by your module.

   Once you discover the models defined by your module, try to delete the corresponding datatables. For example, the model with

   `_name = "bg_vat.bg_vat"`

   will have a corresponding table in the database named 'bg_vat_bg_vat'.
6. Finally, remove or just deactivate the module. Look for a record corresponding to your module in `ir_module_module` datatable. You can delete the record or just set the `state` field to `uninstalled`.

   If you like, you can now delete the module's directory from `addons` but I don't see a reason to do this.

I'm sure I missed some cleaning actions (like the records in the `ir_model*` datatable family). I'm also pretty sure this procedure can easily break your OpenERP installation. Make a backup first. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I edited my question and added the error threw during the uninstall process. Maybe it's good to know that I get this same error when I try to install a module manually (folder in the addons folder then through the installed modules menu)

Comment: As you stated in your question it should be an error in a XML file. I don't see which one exactly. But in is one which line 33 inside a `<record>` element.

Comment: Modules and models may create data everywhere : in ir_model, in their own tables, but also in special postgres tables like pg_class and pg_constraint that are stored in the database's catalog (open catalogs > pg_catalog in pgadmin). The latter tables contain foreign key constraints that need to be dropped via `ALTER TABLE "%s" DROP CONSTRAINT "%s"`.

Answer (score 9):

[Proof of concept](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jtmDM0wfFQ).

There are two ways

1. Apply the Patch of my pull request:

   > https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/12373.patch (git apply /home/user/patch_file.patch)
2. Manually:

   > 1.Go to Terminal > `psql db_name` and Execute the query like:
   >   `update ir_module_module set state='to remove' where name='module_name' and state='installed';`
   >
   > 2.Add `update_module=True` in loading.py before [this line](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/modules/loading.py#L378)

And run the odoo.py or odoo-bin.

This will uninstall the module properly and safely.

Enjoy odoo.
Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: That didn't well OK... `odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 314, in load_modules
    Module.invalidate_cache(['state'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5264, in invalidate_cache
    fields = map(self._fields.__getitem__, fnames)
KeyError: 'state'`

Comment: You need to add the patch in order for this solution to work. Or make changes in your odoo code manually by checking the difference. If you want to see if it works or not, it sure does. Have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jtmDM0wfFQ

Comment: I have tried this method to uninstall the third party module. after module uninstalled. The DB is crashed. and showing key error [field_name]. in odoo 10. Please help me.

Comment: This is the Best Answer! THANKS

Answer (score 3):

Execute the `odoo-bin` script (where you have cloned from the repo on github.com) and start *Odoo Shell* passing your database name (odoo on this example)

```sh
odoo/odoo-bin shell -c conf/odoo.conf -d odoo
```

In the end you should see this output:

```
env: <odoo.api.Environment object at 0x7f601d28b410>
odoo: <module 'odoo' from '/opt/odoo-prod/odoo-server/odoo/__init__.py'>
openerp: <module 'odoo' from '/opt/odoo-prod/odoo-server/odoo/__init__.py'>
self: res.users(1,)
Python 3.7.9 (default, Jun 16 2021, 20:25:14) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on Linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(Console)
>>>
```

Now is possible to call the Odoo API in order to install, upgrade or uninstall addons.

```py
self.env['ir.module.module'].search([('name', '=', 'crm')]).button_immediate_install()
```

or

```py
self.env['ir.module.module'].search([('name', '=', 'crm')]).button_immediate_upgrade()
```

or

```py
self.env['ir.module.module'].search([('name', '=', 'crm')]).button_immediate_uninstall()
```

Source: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-uninstall-a-module-from-command-line-36076

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, i have created a scheduled action (ir.cron), that i run manually:

```py
env['ir.module.module'].search([('name', '=', 'model_name__want_to_remove')]).button_immediate_uninstall()
```

[image]