# How to remove odoo 8 module

Tags: python, module, odoo

I'm learning odoo 8 module programming. I've just created a test module via scaffold command like this:

```
odoo.py scaffold abc addons
```

The module now appear under Settings when I log in. This was just my first test and I haven't installed module "abc" inside web user interface. Instead I want to remove it. I've deleted the content of "abc" in /opt/odoo/addons restarted the server (Ubuntu 14.04) but the module "abc" still appears under settings in web gui. How can I "purge" my "abc" module. Is there a reverse command to scaffold?

Answer (score 0):

You removed the physical data from your system, but the entry of that module is still there in the database. If you want to remove that module from the odoo than you should do "uninstall" of that module and further if you don't want that module even in the listing than you should delete that record and for that you should switch you module listing to "list view" and select that record and delete it. Then later on if you don't want that module for ever than you can remove from your computer system.

Comment: But how do I "uninstall" it if I haven't even installed it via web gui. All I've done is run the "scaffold" command. Can you please be more specific.

Comment: You are right. In settings menu in web gui I switch to list view, put a check mark on my "abc" module and select delete from the "More" button. Solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

simple when restart the server the use this in command line

```
./odoo.py -d databasename --db-filter databasename -u base
```

and see the module list is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to modules form view, choose `abc`  in `more menu` click on `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting/Purging the obsolete modules and related data in odoo V8:

1.Download the module Database_cleanup (not existing in odoo v8)
Click here https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/database_cleanup/

2.Place it in the folder of addons or custom path set for odoo

3.Restart the odoo server and Postgresql (if needed)

4.Update the module list in odoo

5.Install the database cleanup to delete the modules ,models,columns,tables,data entries and menu entries,that is found under settings-->database cleanup then choose the required details

Answer (score 0):

There are some manual ways but have a look at

1.My pull request: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/12373

2.Stackoverflow answer:
[How to uninstall manually openerp module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485630/how-to-uninstall-manually-openerp-module#answer-41760541)

This will help.
Enjoy odoo.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party, but this may be useful to someone.

I had uninstalled an Odoo 10 module via the web GUI and deleted it from addons, but it still showed up in the list of apps.

I found there was an entry in the table for the module with a state of 'to be installed', so I deleted it by firing up psql and manually deleting the record:

```
psql -h <hostname> -d <database> -U odoo
select name, state from ir_module_module order by name;
delete from ir_module_module where name = 'my_uninstalled_app';
```

I refreshed the Apps page and it no longer appeared.